# Use of MVC array when creating polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use an two dimensional array of points to create a polygon with Google maps api. Here is my code:

```
console.log(points)
mvc = new google.maps.MVCArray(points)
console.log(mvc.getArray())
console.log(mvc)

poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: mvc,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

//poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray(points));
```

Here is what console output looks like

```
[[44.465332670616895, 26.143829190988], [44.466098355169805, 26.1465114000029], [44.4652867292244, 26.1474555375761], [44.4646435459323, 26.1463826539702], [44.4643066375701, 26.145588720101802]]

[[44.465332670616895, 26.143829190988], [44.466098355169805, 26.1465114000029], [44.4652867292244, 26.1474555375761], [44.4646435459323, 26.1463826539702], [44.4643066375701, 26.145588720101802]]

mg { b=[5], gm_accessors_={...}, length=5, more...}
```

And this error:

```
Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: [object Object]
```

for the line where I try to use the MVC array to create polygon, or assign it as polygon path.

Now what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items of the array assigned to the path of a polygon are expected to be LatLng-objects, you must first convert the values:

```
for(var i=0; i < points.length; ++i){
     points[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(points[i][0]),
                                        Number(points[i][1]));
}
```